# Read values from a column in a file

Tags: c

I am trying to read values from a file from a specific column (ignoring the first number) and then find the average of that column. So far I have this code which works for reading and finding the average of the line however not for the column.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    int id;
    float mark1;
    float mark2;
    float mark3;
    float mark4;
    int number;
    float average;

    fp= fopen("grades.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File cannot be opened");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f %f %f", &number, &mark1, &mark2, &mark3, &mark4 ) != EOF){
        //code to calculate average and print output
        //Below is the code I used to find the average of the line (not what I want to do)
        average = (mark1 + mark2 + mark3+ mark4)/4;
        printf("Average for %d : %.2f\n", number, average);

    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

So in the file there is a total of 5 columns, the first is the ID which is just and interger value (int number) and the others numbers are all floats.

FILE CONTENTS:

```
12345 60 30 63.2 95
54321 54.2 49 40.5 80
15243 99.5 100 90 98
```

Comment: You do know about structures? You do know about arrays? You do (obviously) know about loops. Explore those three concepts and experiment with them.

Comment: If you do not want `number`, then there i no need to fill it. `fscanf` will allow the use of the `assignment suppression operator '*'` (e.g. `fscanf(fp, "%*d %f %f %f %f",  &mark1, &mark2, &mark3, &mark4 )` Using `'*'` will effectively read and discard the value without adding to the match count.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I completely forgot about arrays, thank you.

@DavidC.Rankin Sorry but I think you misunderstood, it is not that I don't want `number` but I just wanted to be able to read values from each column and add those together rather than a row. Thank you.

Comment: this line: `printf("File cannot be opened");` fails to tell the user the root cause of the problem with opening the file.  Suggest: `perror("fopen failed for inpput of grades.txt");  Which tells the user what file failed.  The perror() function will also output the relevant system error message (selected by the value in errno) that says why the system thinks the call to fopen() failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a variable `sum` to add all the values of a particular column, and later use that to get the average, something like

```
int sum=0, n=0;

while(fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f %f %f", &number, &mark1, &mark2, &mark3, &mark4 ) != EOF){
    //code to calculate average and print output
    //Below is the code I used to find the average of the line (not what I want to do)
    average = (mark1 + mark2 + mark3+ mark4)/4;
    printf("Average for %d : %.2f\n", number, average);

    sum += mark2 //this can be any mark depending on your requirement
    n++;         //this is to keep track of the number of lines

}

printf("the average of column 2 is %d", (sum/n) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    int id;
    float mark1;
    float mark2;
    float mark3;
    float mark4;
    int number;
    float somme[4];
    int nbLg=0;
    int i;
    fp= fopen("grades.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File cannot be opened");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f %f %f", &number, &mark1, &mark2, &mark3, &mark4 ) != EOF){
        nbLg++;
        somme[0]+= mark1;
        somme[1]+= mark2;
        somme[2]+= mark3;
        somme[3]+= mark4;

    }

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
        printf("Average for %d : %.2f\n", i+1, somme[i] / (float) nbLg);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Don't you think It could be easier to understand replacing `somme` with `sum` ?

Comment: Yes it would but this was only an example of how I would approach it not something I would use one for one.

Answer (score 0):

the following code is:

- more complex than necessary to keep it simple, easy to follow.
- compiles cleanly
- performs the desired function

A bit of thinking and paper//pencil work would have given you similar logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{

    FILE *fp;

    float mark1;
    float mark1Average = 0.0f;
    float mark2;
    float mark2Average = 0.0f;
    float mark3;
    float mark3Average = 0.0f;
    float mark4;
    float mark4Average = 0.0f;
    int   number;
    int   numberAverage = 0;


    fp= fopen("grades.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File cannot be opened");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // get first line to initialize average values
    if  ( 5 != fscanf( fp, "%d %f %f %f %f",
                &numberAverage,
                &mark1Average,
                &mark2Average,
                &mark3Average,
                &mark4Average )
        )
    { // then fscanf failed
        perror( "fscanf for first line of grades.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fscanf successful

    while(5 == fscanf(fp, "%d %f %f %f %f", &number, &mark1, &mark2, &mark3, &mark4 ))
    {
        numberAverage = (numberAverage+number)/2;
        mark1Average  = (mark1Average+mark1)/2.0f;
        mark2Average  = (mark2Average+mark2)/2.0f;
        mark3Average  = (mark3Average+mark3)/2.0f;
        mark4Average  = (mark4Average+mark4)/2.0f;
    }

    printf( "numberAverage: %d\n", numberAverage);
    printf( "mark1Average:  %f\n", mark1Average);
    printf( "mark2Average:  %f\n", mark2Average);
    printf( "mark3Average:  %f\n", mark3Average);
    printf( "mark4Average:  %f\n", mark4Average);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: it is better to check the returned value from `fscanf()` for successful input conversions because any other value is an error.   If you wanted to recover from mal-formed lines in the file, the read each line (via `fgets()`) into a buffer and use `sscanf()` to extract each field